# how to make connection between two classes in python3

Tags: python, class

hi i have two classes `Book` and `Library` with a text file (my_text.txt including these data

```
danial feldroy - two scoops of django
james brown - python3 with examples
```

in the `Book` class

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self,author,title):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Author: {self.author}, Title: {self.title}"
```

Library takes one input variable, name, which is a string that represents the name of the library

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        books = {}

# add_book takes a Book instance, and checks to see if the Book is not in self.books. If it's not
# then a new key value pair is added to the dictionary. If it is in books, then the data stored
# in the key 'available' is updated for that book.
    def add_book(self, book_inst):
        if (book_inst.author, book_inst.title) not in self.books:
           self.books[(book_inst.author, book_inst.title)] = {"checked_out": 0, "available": 1}
        else:
           self.books[(book_inst.author, book_inst.title)]["available"] +=1

# can_check_out will take a Book instance as input. Checks to see if the book is in the dictionary
# of books. If it is, then it checks to see if the value of available is 1 or more. If it is, then it 
# returns True. If it does not, then it returns False. If the book cannot be found, then a string is returned
# to the user to inform them of this occurrence.
    def can_check_out(self, book_inst):
        book = (book_inst.author, book_inst.title)
        if book in self.books:
            if self.books[book]["available"] >= 1:                
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return "The book you are looking for has not been added to this library yet."

f = open('my_text.txt').readlines()
book_list = []
for book in f:
    instance = tuple((x.strip() for x in book.split('-')))
    book_list.append(instance) # the variable instance should be assigned an instance of the Book class.
```

There is an instance of the `Library` class called books; i have to add all of the Book instances to books variable

```
books = Library("Hatcher Graduate Library")
#i have to write the code here
```

i need to add data to the Book

i have to access to Book through books like this

```
print(books.can_check_out(Book('Statistics for all', 'jim james')))
```

i much appreciate your helps ..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into class inheritance, it is basically a connector between two classes, where one derives from the other.

Comment: no , this is homework , they dont let us to use inheritance